# Docmd.acbrowsetoform where clause

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

Ok So here is my code.  I think I'm close but when the frmCondition/Concerns Update form opens it ask for the strCBOProperty value.  I know it is probably a syntax error, but I don't know what it is.

```
Private Sub btnLogin_Click()
Dim strCBOPassword As String
Dim strPassword As String
Dim strCBOProperty As String

Selectnull

strCBOProperty = Me.cboProperty.Column(0)
strCBOPassword = Me.cboProperty.Column(1)
strPassword = Me.txtPassword

If strCBOPassword = strPassword Then
    MsgBox "Login Successful!"
    DoCmd.BrowseTo acBrowseToForm, "frmCondition/Concerns Update", , "[Forms]![frmCondition/Concerns Update]!cbopropertyname = strCBOProperty"
Else
    MsgBox "Invalid Password"
End If
```

End Sub

Private Sub Selectnull()
    If IsNull(Me.cboProperty) Then
        MsgBox "Please select a property", vbOKOnly
    ElseIf IsNull(Me.txtPassword) Then
        MsgBox "Please enter a password", vbOKOnly
    End If
End Sub

Comment: See my answer. Use `DoCmd.OpenForm` to open a from, and build the WhereCondition.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you need something like this:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCondition", WhereCondition:="PropertyName='" & Me.cboProperty.Value & "'"
```

If not, tell us more about the contents of `cboProperty` and the data type of the property column in the conditions table.

If you have the value in a variable:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCondition", WhereCondition:="PropertyName='" & strCBOProperty & "'"
```

The variable must be outside of the string.

Using named parameters makes sure you get the parameter right. You have it on the `FilterName` position.

Comment: Ok, I did that: `If strCBOPassword = strPassword Then
        MsgBox "Login Successful!"
        DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCondition/Concerns Update", , "cbopropertyname = strCBOProperty"`  But I am still geting a prompt for the strCBOProperty.  Any ideas why?

Comment: So I got the errors fixed but when I open up the form it is not filtering.  Here is the openform statement:  `DoCmd.OpenForm "frmCondition/Concerns Update", acNormal, , "'cbopropertyname= " & strCBOProperty & "'", acFormPropertySettings, acWindowNormal, "'"`

Comment: Please take a close look at my answer, and see where the single quotes are located. @ChrisR